# Change Default storage location of SQLite running inside Kubernetes Pod

Tags: sqlite, kubernetes

The Default storage location of SQLite database in a pod of kubernetes is `/home/me/`.
When every I create a database it gets stored inside `/home/me/` directory.

I want to change this to `/home/database`.

I tried changing it myself by trying to change data_store_directory like this

```
PRAGMA data_store_directory; 

PRAGMA data_store_directory = 'directory-name';
```

But this doesn't writes anything inside data_store_directory.

Can anyone please specify how to customize the storage location of SQLite database running inside a pod in kubernetes.

Comment: The `data_store_directory` PRAGMA is [deprecated](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_data_store_directory), and you should avoid using it. How are you creating your database?

Comment: Yes, the data_store_directory PRAGMA is deprecated. Is there another means to change the default storage location of SQLite database in a pod of kubernetes.

I am creating database like this :

[cloud-user@ose3-int-a-master-1 ~]$ sqlite3 testDB.db

sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  --------------------
0    main             /home/me/testDB.db

Comment: Yes, specify the full path when creating the database: `sqlite3 /home/database/testDB.db;`